# Problem refering to appendix using the sysbio class

Tags: cross-referencing, document-classes

With the MWE:

```
\documentclass{sysbio}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Some thing in \ref{app::a}
Some thing in \autoref{app::a}

\appendix
\section{some appendix}
\label{app::a}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Neither `\ref` nor `\autoref` works as I expected:

[image]

`\ref` gives empty link while `\autoref` just shows "section". I think it might be a problem with the sysbio class, how could I refer to the appendices with something like "Appendix A"?
Link to the example overleaf project: [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/spmgcwnxshsj#a29b15)

Comment: For not numbered sections I would suggest to use `\nameref` instead of `\ref` or `\autoref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sysbio` document class runs `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`. Therefore, by default, section-level headers (and all other subordinate-level headers too) aren't numbered. And because the LaTeX `\label`-`\ref` cross-referencing machinery requires the objects that are to be cross-referenced to be numbered, neither `\ref` nor `\autoref` have a chance of functioning as expected.

The remedy? I suggest you run `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` either in the preamble -- to have all section-level headers in the document to be numbered -- or immediately after `\appendix`, in which case only the section-level headers in the appendix portion of the document are numbered.

[image]

```
\documentclass{sysbio}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction} % an unnumbered section header

Something in \ref{app::a}. Something in \autoref{app::a}.

\appendix
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1} % either here or in the preamble

\section{An appendix} % % a numbered (lettered?) section header
\label{app::a}
Some text \dots

\end{document}
```